# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, jestjs

Okay so I've gotten pretty far in creating the React Component for ChartJS, however when testing I get the following error:

```
FAIL  lib\chart\chart.test.tsx
  ● renders without crashing

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

      at Object.acquireContext (node_modules/chart.js/src/platforms/platform.dom.js:189:19)
      at Chart.construct (node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.controller.js:72:27)
      at new Chart (node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.js:7:8)
      at Chart.Object.<anonymous>.Chart.renderChart (lib/chart/chart.tsx:233:26)
      at Chart.Object.<anonymous>.Chart.componentDidMount (lib/chart/chart.tsx:42:10)
      at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:264:25
      at measureLifeCyclePerf (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
      at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:263:11
      at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (node_modules/react-dom/lib/CallbackQueue.js:76:22)
      at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80:26)
      at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:209:25)
      at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:156:16)
      at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:126:15)
      at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:143:20)
      at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
      at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
      at Object._renderNewRootComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:319:18)
      at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:401:32)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:422:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (lib/chart/chart.test.tsx:7:12)
          at Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)

  × renders without crashing (275ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.314s, estimated 3s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

However, I've spent a long time looking over the code and haven't been able to figure out why it refuses to work properly. The error starts at the `renderChart()` function at creating a new chart instance. My first guess would be the for some reason it's not registering the canvas element despite being called by its id.  But when the content of renderChart is moved into the render() function it still gives the same error. Here's the code being tested:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ClassNames from 'classnames'
import * as ChartJS from 'chart.js'
const IsEqual = require('lodash.isequal')
const Find = require('lodash.find')
const subChart = require('chart.js')

interface IChartProps {
  /** The user-defined classes */
  readonly className?: string
  readonly width?: number
  readonly height?: number
  readonly reRender?: boolean

  readonly type: ChartJS.ChartType
  readonly data: ChartJS.ChartData
  readonly options: ChartJS.ChartOptions
  readonly getDatasetAtEvent?: Function
  readonly getElementAtEvent?: Function
  readonly getElementsAtEvent?: Function
  readonly onElementsClick?: Function
  readonly datasetKeyProvider?: Function
}

interface IChartState {
  /** Add your states here */
}

export class Chart extends React.Component<IChartProps, IChartState> {
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  private chartInstance: any
  private shadowData: {}
  constructor(props: IChartProps) {
    super(props)
  }

  public componentWillMount() {
    // this.chartInstance = undefined
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.renderChart()
  }

  // public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IChartProps) {}

  public shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IChartProps, nextState: IChartState) {
    const props = this.props
    if (nextProps.reRender === true) {
      return true
    }

    if (props.height !== nextProps.height || props.width !== nextProps.width) {
      return true
    }

    if (props.type !== nextProps.type) {
      return true
    }

    if (!IsEqual(props.options, nextProps.options)) {
      return true
    }

    const nextData = this.transformDataProp(nextProps)

    if (!IsEqual(this.shadowData, nextData)) {
      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  // public componentWillUpdate(nextProps: IChartProps, nextState: IChartState) {}

  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IChartProps, prevState: IChartState) {
    if (this.props.reRender) {
      this.chartInstance.destroy()
      this.renderChart()
      return
    }
    this.updateChart()
  }

  public transformDataProp(props: IChartProps) {
    const data = props.data
    if (typeof data === 'function') {
      const node = document.getElementById('bar-chart') as HTMLCanvasElement
      return data(node)
    } else {
      return data
    }
  }

  public memoizeDataProps(props?: IChartProps) {
    if (!this.props.data) {
      return
    }
    const data = this.transformDataProp(this.props)

    this.shadowData = {
      ...data,
      datasets:
        data.datasets &&
        data.datasets.map((set: string[]) => {
          return { ...set }
        })
    }
    return data
  }

  public updateChart() {
    const options = this.props.options

    const data = this.memoizeDataProps(this.props)

    if (!this.chartInstance) {
      return
    }

    if (options) {
      this.chartInstance.options = subChart.helpers.configMerge(
        this.chartInstance.options,
        options
      )
    }

    let currentDatasets =
      (this.chartInstance.config.data &&
        this.chartInstance.config.data.datasets) ||
      []
    const nextDatasets = data.datasets || []

    const currentDatasetKeys = currentDatasets.map(
      this.props.datasetKeyProvider
    )
    const nextDatasetKeys = nextDatasets.map(this.props.datasetKeyProvider)
    const newDatasets = nextDatasets.filter(
      (d: object) =>
        currentDatasetKeys.indexOf(this.props.datasetKeyProvider(d)) === -1
    )

    for (let idx = currentDatasets.length - 1; idx >= 0; idx -= 1) {
      const currentDatasetKey = this.props.datasetKeyProvider(
        currentDatasets[idx]
      )
      if (nextDatasetKeys.indexOf(currentDatasetKey) === -1) {
        // deleted series
        currentDatasets.splice(idx, 1)
      } else {
        const retainedDataset = Find(
          nextDatasets,
          (d: object) => this.props.datasetKeyProvider(d) === currentDatasetKey
        )
        if (retainedDataset) {
          // update it in place if it is a retained dataset
          currentDatasets[idx].data.splice(retainedDataset.data.length)
          retainedDataset.data.forEach((point: number, pid: number) => {
            currentDatasets[idx].data[pid] = retainedDataset.data[pid]
          })
          // const { data, ...otherProps } = retainedDataset
          currentDatasets[idx] = {
            data: currentDatasets[idx].data,
            ...currentDatasets[idx],
            ...retainedDataset.otherProps
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // finally add any new series
    newDatasets.forEach((d: object) => currentDatasets.push(d))
    const { datasets, ...rest } = data

    this.chartInstance.config.data = {
      ...this.chartInstance.config.data,
      ...rest
    }

    this.chartInstance.update()
  }

  public componentWillUnmount() {
    this.chartInstance.destroy()
  }

  public onClickEvent = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>) => {
    // this.props.getDatasetAtEvent &&
    this.props.getDatasetAtEvent(
      this.chartInstance.getDatasetAtEvent(event),
      event
    )

    // this.props.getElementAtEvent &&
    this.props.getElementAtEvent(
      this.chartInstance.getElementAtEvent(event),
      event
    )

    // this.props.getElementsAtEvent &&
    this.props.getElementsAtEvent(
      this.chartInstance.getElementsAtEvent(event),
      event
    )

    // this.props.onElementsClick &&
    this.props.onElementsClick(
      this.chartInstance.getElementsAtEvent(event),
      event
    )
  }

  public render() {
    const className = ClassNames('chart', this.props.className)

    // bar.update()
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <canvas
          id="chart-instance"
          width={this.props.width ? this.props.width : '400'}
          height={this.props.height ? this.props.height : '400'}
          onClick={this.onClickEvent}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

  public renderChart() {
    const { options, type, data } = this.props
    const node = document.getElementById('chart-instance') as HTMLCanvasElement
    // const data = this.memoizeDataProps()

    this.chartInstance = new ChartJS(node, {
      type,
      data,
      options
    })
  }
}
```

can someone help me figure out why this won't work properly?

Comment: the error is telling you what the problem is. Whatever you're calling ```length``` on doesn't exist. Can you post the test that is failing? Does the component render even though that test is failing?

Comment: Since you haven't posted test itself, I suppose `length` is a property of some element. Try like this:
`const wrapper = mount(<YourElement />);
wrapper.find('ElementYourWantLengthOf').props().length`

You might also be calling `length` on an array of nodes returned by `find()`. Then, obviously, `find()` finds nothing which might be a consequence of a component not being mounted properly.

Anyways, post your test code, then we'll see.

Answer (score -1):

It might because of this:

`currentDatasets[idx].data.splice(retainedDataset.data.length)`

You should have a check on `retainedDataset.data` also:

`if (retainedDataset && retainedDataset.data) { ... }`